# EaselJS Matrix2D

Tags: image, html, canvas, matrix, easeljs

I am new in EaselJS. Can you tell me how to make matrix worked for Image. Can you tell me what is wrong with my code

For example

```
        matx = new Matrix2D(1,2,3,4,5,6);
        image.addChild(matx);
        stage.update();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I'm not sure if this should be an "answer" or "comment", but it looks like this question was posed and responded to (by Grant Skinner) on the EaselJS discussion forums:

http://community.createjs.com/discussions/easeljs/246-easeljs-matrix2d

Comment: This link ist down.